# expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled() error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Enzyme/Jest to write a test for a function on my component that is triggered through an onClick of a material's menu icon. The function is passed as props to the component. When writing test, it gives me error on simulating click.

```
import React from 'react';
    import scssstyles from './ToggleSideNavComponent.scss';
    class ToggleSideNavComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <a
              id="toggle_sidebar_btn"
              className={scssstyles.menuIcon}
              onClick={this.props.handleSideNavToggle}
              >
              <i id="menu" className="material-icons menu-icon" style={{fontSize:30}}>menu</i>
            </a>
        );
      }
    }


    module.exports = ToggleSideNavComponent;
```

**TEST**

```
import expect from 'expect';
import React from 'react';
import {mount, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import ToggleSideNavComponent from  './ToggleSideNavComponent';
import sinon from 'sinon';

function setup() {
    const props = {
        handleSideNavToggle: sinon.spy()

    };

    return {
        props: props,
        wrapper: shallow(<ToggleSideNavComponent {...props} />) 
    };
}

describe('ToggleSideNavComponent', () => {
    it('should have menu icon', () => {
        const component = setup();
        expect(component.wrapper.find('a #menu').length).toBe(1);

        component.wrapper.find('#toggle_sidebar_btn #menu').simulate('click');
        expect(component.props.handleSideNavToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

**error :**

```
ToggleSideNavComponent › should have menu icon

    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function proxy]

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/app/Header/NavLeftList/ToggleSideNavComponent/ToggleSideNavComponent.spec.js:25:94)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: I have tried with :
component.wrapper.find('#toggle_sidebar_btn').simulate('click');
component.wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');

nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jest, you should use Jest's spies, rather than Sinon.

```
const props = {
    handleSideNavToggle: jest.fn()
};
```

Comment: have tried with jest.fn() as well. Result is the same error. Looks like i'm missing something which i'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code but changed `shallow rendering` to `full DOM rendering` using `mount` and everything works fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import ToggleSideNavComponent from  './ToggleSideNavComponent';

function setup() {
    const props = {
            handleSideNavToggle: jest.fn()

    };

    return {
        props: props,
        wrapper: mount(<ToggleSideNavComponent {...props} />)
    };
}

describe('ToggleSideNavComponent', () => {
    it('should have menu icon', () => {
        const component = setup();
        expect(component.wrapper.find('a #menu').length).toBe(1);

        component.wrapper.find('#toggle_sidebar_btn #menu').simulate('click');
        expect(component.props.handleSideNavToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();

        component.wrapper.unmount(); // don't forget to use unmount() after mounting
    });
});
```

seems like there is a problem accessing `props` when using `shallow rendering`

If you only want to test the behavior of the `handleSideNavToggle` function (just unit test this function) then I don't recommend doing it using `simulate` because you don't need to test React's event wiring nor the browser's, instead you could have shallow rendered the parent component which provides this prop function to your component `ToggleSideNavComponent` and call this method using suitable arguments and assert results, for example:

```
describe('ToggleSideNavComponentParent', () => {
    it('test parent component function', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<ToggleSideNavComponentParent/>);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        let e = prepareSuitableEventObject();
        instance.handleSideNavToggle(e);

        // do your assertions here
    });
});

function prepareSuitableEventObject() {
    // construct an object and return it
}
```